# Export data from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, bcp

I am trying to push data from Excel to SQL Server using `bcp` command for multiple tables. Currently I have setup my code such as it creates the text files of the data(in a loop) which needs to be pushed and then run a `bcp` command mentioned below

```
bcp dbname.schema_name.table_name out C:\table_name.txt -n -S localhost -U username -P password -b 10000
```

However I would like to do away with the loop and want to run a single `bcp` command with names of multiple tables as first argument and different text files as second arguments. I tried finding the solution for this online but couldn't come up with anything.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Just a bit of background: the reason I want to do away with the loop and run a single command is, I am observing strange behavior of my code which is when I step through my code it is able to push all the data to SQL Server, However when I run the entire process at once by clicking on the button to which macro is assigned, the code still runs but don't push any data to SQL Server.

To resolve this I tried putting doevents just after the `bcp` command but all went in vain, then I setup a wait for 5 seconds just after bcp command and it seems to work, but I feel setting up wait is kinda risky business I will never be sure what should be the wait time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single BCP command can only push data to a single table.   There is no way to pass multiple table names to a single BCP command.

Comment: @Thanks for the prompt response, Just wanted to check if you can provide any pointers on why my code is behaving in a way as i pointed in background provided by me in my question.

Comment: I have had similar behavior when using Excel with SSIS..the connection doesn't drop quickly enough and the connection for the next command can't open.  Putting in "waits" is the standard solution to the best of my knowledge.   I've done it before.   5 seconds should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with a good old fashioned loop to handle the task.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sCustomerId, sFirstName, sLastName As String

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ASUSBOOK\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=ExcelDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            sCustomerId = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sFirstName = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            sLastName = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (CustomerId, FirstName, LastName) values ('" & sCustomerId & "', '" & sFirstName & "', '" & sLastName & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox "Customers imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

Also, check out this link.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

If the loop scenario is just too slow for you, consider saving your data sets as CSV files and do a bulk insert.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO
--Drop the table to clean up database.
DROP TABLE CSVTest
GO
```

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/